# HTTP Get Request in Angular

Tags: angular, http, get

I have this url=https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2 and I am using a get request to fetch the data.

user.ts is an interface

```
export interface User {
    id:number,
    email:string,
    first_name:string,
    last_name:string,
    avatar:string
}
```

user.service.ts is a service

```
getAllUsers() :  Observable<User[]> {
  return this.http.get<User[]>("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");    
}
```

user.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  public user =[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService.getAllUsers().subscribe(data => this.user = data)
  }

}
```

I want to get the data object from the response object of 'GET' request and make a array of users.

```
Error: src/app/user/user.component.ts:16:54 - error TS2322: Type 'User[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.

16     this.userService.getAllUsers().subscribe(data => this.user = data)
                                                        ~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/user/user.component.ts:16:54 - error TS2322: Type 'User[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
  Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'never'.

16     this.userService.getAllUsers().subscribe(data => this.user = data)
```

Comment: you need to subscribe to the get request. then you can access the data. `get(...).subscribe(response => console.log(response))`

Comment: I believe it is `data.data` that you want.

Comment: `public user: User[] = []` should do the trick

Comment: Why are you assigning a value to `user` before ngOnInit anyways?

Answer (score 1):

What about changing the user type in your component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  public users: User [] =[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService
      .getAllUsers()
     .subscribe(data => this.user = data)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually needed to create an interim object to access the **Users**[] - that is why you were having that type error. You can fix that by using pipe and passing data you want inside the object back to the component.

Let me know if you need further help.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scratch-pad?file=src/app/user/user.component.html)